# Why does this sentence 'I find it difficult to speak English fluently' have no copula?

Tags: verbs, ellipsis, to-infinitive, objects

Moreover, is 'I find it is difficult to speak English fluently' incorrect or unnatural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a copular sentence!

The verb is "find", used in the idiom  "find it (easy/difficult/hard) +to infinitive"

The sentence does not have a copula, but it does have a linking verb "find".  Unlike other linking verbs (like is, or seem) the verb find has a direct object and a complement (which is an adjective).

This is idiomatic to the verb "find", but there are some other verbs that allow for a similar construction:  "I made him happy".  Note that the word "it" is an object, not a subject.  You can say I find **him** difficult to understand" but not "I find **he** difficult to understand".

You can form a sentence like "I find it is difficult..." This is a quite different structure.  Now "it" is a subject in a content clause.  This is equivalent to "I find that it is difficult...". And note that you would say "I find he is difficult to understand".  Observe the subject form of "he".

So, the sentence "I find it difficult to..." is *not* a reduced form of "I find it is difficult...". These apparently similar sentences have different syntax.

Using "find it difficult" is natural and correct.  Using the form with "is" would be rare and rather unnatural.